# Dynamically display certain column data from query object using vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a query Object that returns 357 columns (e.g, fullRecord). For a certain portion of my UI, I want to query through a subset of about 125 of those items and display them in a list. I have the column names of those items I want to display in an array (e.g., colsWanted).

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically iterate through the "colsWanted" array and display the appropriate "fullRecord.colsWanted(Item)" in the vuetify interface. I've tried what feels like a million different iterations of this but here is the latest which shows an error:

```html
    <v-flex v-for="(value, index) in colsWanted" :key="value">
      <v-card flat>
        <span v-if="fullRecord[value] in fullRecord">
          <strong>{{ index }}. {{ fullRecord[value] }}</strong>
        </span>
        <span v-else class="error--text">Not Available</span>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
```

I actually get no errors at all from this; but no results are displayed when they should in fact return results.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: @Flame Just a comment about the edit. My linter preferences push stacked, nested formatting of the attributes. Not sure if others have settings the same way but thought I'd share.

Comment: well this is easier to read I reckon. Situation differs with more attributes ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object key selection is wrong:

```
<span v-if="fullRecord[value] in fullRecord">
```

`fullRecord[value]` will retrieve the value of the `value` key, which will not be `in fullRecord`.

What you should be using is:

```
<span v-if="value in fullRecord">
```

or

```
<span v-if="fullRecord.hasOwnProperty(value)">
```

Also I would rename `value` to `key` since thats what it actually is.

Comment: Thanks much for the feedback. I actually decided to go a completely separate route but I'll hold onto the details for the future.